# Require.js and Imager.js undefined function

Tags: javascript, requirejs, undefined, amd

I have a problem adding the Imager.js library to require.js load, the script work perfect without require.js

Main.js

```
define([
        'jquery',
        'bootstrap',
        'imager',
        'video'
    ],
    function($) {
        'use strict';
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
        $('#bvideo').magnificPopup({
            type: 'inline'
        });
        videojs('video-cdve', {
            'controls': true,
            'autoplay': false,
            'preload': 'auto',
            'width': 'auto',
            'height': 'auto'
        });
        new Imager({
            availableWidths: {
                320: '320x240',
                640: 'large',
                1024: 'large_x2',
            }
        });
    });
```

I obtain this error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Imager is not defined

When i define Imager

```
define([
        'jquery',
        'bootstrap',
        'imager',
        'video'
    ],
    function($, Imager) {
        'use strict';
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
        $('#bvideo').magnificPopup({
            type: 'inline'
        });
        videojs('video-cdve', {
            'controls': true,
            'autoplay': false,
            'preload': 'auto',
            'width': 'auto',
            'height': 'auto'
        });
        new Imager({
            availableWidths: {
                320: '320x240',
                640: 'large',
                1024: 'large_x2',
            }
        });
    });
```

And now i recive this error

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Whats happend? How i add correctly this library with require??

Comment: `Imager` is 2nd when passing parameters, but your importing it 3rd in your `define` array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameters are bound to modules in the same order as how you list them in the requirements so when you do this:

```
define([
        'jquery',
        'bootstrap',
        'imager',
        'video'
    ],
    function($, Imager) {
```

you are binding `Imager` to the value of the `'bootstrap'` module. Change the order:

```
define([
        'jquery',
        'imager',
        'bootstrap',
        'video'
    ],
    function($, Imager) {
```

I also considered whether you'd need a shim for Imager but I see in their [code](https://github.com/BBC-News/Imager.js/blob/master/Imager.js) that they detect an AMD environment and call `define`.